# Inline r to show variable value in a markdown table

Tags: r, r-markdown

Using RMarkdown.
I define `tau=10` in an R script, which I read in to a Rmd file using `read_chunk(example.R)`.
I invoke the `example` chunk.
I would like to show the value of `tau` in the table defined below.
no matter how I try I cannot get the r code to evaluate.

Appreciate any hints or tips.

````
```{r example, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warnings=FALSE, results='asis'}
```
```{r tbl, message=FALSE, warnings=FALSE, results='asis'}
tbl <- "
| Parameter                           | Value         |
|-------------------------------------|:-------------:| 
|  $$\\frac{\\partial}{\\partial} $$  | `r tau `      |
"
cat(tbl)
```
````

Comment: Your table would work if you just included it in the body of the text, without catting it in a code chunk - do you need to do extra processing that prevents you doing that?

Comment: Thanks @Marius, for my table code I'm following the SO advice for [Simple manual RMarkdown tables that look good in HTML, PDF and DOCX](http://r.duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F19997242%2Fddg%2320008018)

Comment: OK, I don't really understand why `cat` is used in that question either - as far as I know catting the table in and including it in the body of the text should be equivalent for a static table (without inline code or `paste`d values). I've tested the examples in the linked question and see the same results whether `cat`ing or including in text. Try including your table in the text body and see how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Marius mentioned, just place the table details in the text rather than inside a code chunk and then make the inline call to `tau`.

That is, change the contents of your rmarkdown file to look like this:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
tau <- 10
```

| Parameter                           | Value         |
|-------------------------------------|:-------------:| 
|  $$\frac{\partial}{\partial} $$     |   `r tau `    |
````

**EDIT**:

If the table text needs to be kept within the code chunk for some reason then you could try:

````
```{r tbl, message=FALSE, warnings=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
tbl <- c("
| Parameter                           | Value         |
|-------------------------------------|:-------------:| 
|  $$\\frac{\\partial}{\\partial} $$  | ", tau, "     |
")
cat(tbl, sep="")
```
````

(Note `tau` is defined locally rather than via an external script in this example)

Comment: Think you have to modify the math slightly as the backslashes no longer need to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks Marius, extra backslashes removed.  Both code snippets in the edited answer should now render correctly

Answer (score 1):

When using inline R for Rmarkdown, this is a start:

````
```{r}
tau=10
```

| Parameter                           | Value               |
|-------------------------------------|:-------------------:| 
|  $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial} $$    | `r tau`             |
````

But if you want to do something more complex like ad-lib a calculation, bold, or color the font, that's when you want to get in the habit of using **paste0()**, which allows you to smoothly mix languages:

````
```{r}
tau=10
```

| Parameter                           | Value                                                
|
|-------------------------------------|:-------------------------------------------------:| 
|  $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial} $$    | `r tau`                                           |
|  $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial} $$    | `r paste0('**',tau,'**')`                         |
|  $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial} $$    | `r paste0('\\textcolor[RGB]{0,205,102}{',tau,'}')`|
|  $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial} $$    | `r paste0('**','!=',tau-1,'**')`                  | 
|  $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial} $$    | `r paste0('\\textcolor[RGB]{255,0,0}{',tau-1,'}')`|
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That was a useful tip. I accepted @markdly's edited answer because it was changed to conform with the problem posed, i.e. the cat string.

Comment: @Hedgehog - No problem. Both tools are definitely helpful to know.